# Get all posts and their subordinate posts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I hope you can help me. I am using SQL Server 2016 and am trying to generate some code to return all posts and all their subordinate posts.

The following code is as far as I have got so far:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    P.[Post Number],
    P.[Authoriser Post Number],
    P.[Post Name]
FROM
    Structure.Post P
WHERE
    P.[Authoriser Post Number] IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    C.[Post Number],
    C.[Authoriser Post Number],
    C.[Post Name]
FROM
    Structure.Post C
JOIN
    CTE P ON C.[Authoriser Post Number] = P.[Post Number]
) SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
[Post Number]   [Authoriser Post Number]    [Post Name]
85              NULL                        CEO
86              85                          Development Director
87              85                          Sales Director
88              85                          HR Director
89              88                          HR Manager
90              89                          HR Officer
91              89                          Recruitment Officer
92              89                          HR Assistant
93              87                          Sales Manager
94              87                          Sales Manager
97              94                          Salesman
98              94                          Sales Support Officer
95              93                          Salesman
96              93                          Sales Support Officer
99              86                          Web Design Manager
100             86                          SQL Manager
104             100                         Project Manager
105             100                         SQL Developer
101             99                          Web Developer
102             99                          C# Developer
103             99                          Project Manager
```

What I want is for the Post "CEO" to show all post numbers, then the Post "Development Director" to show all post numbers for all posts below them in the hierarchy etc.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: can you just show what exactly you want and what tables you have?and also the connection between tables?

Comment: For this exercise I am only using the [Structure].[Post] table. Each Post has an [Authoriser Post Number] which is who authorises leave etc. I need to see what posts, directly or indirectly, manage what other posts. So, CEO manages all posts in the organisation structure but Development Director manages only the posts below him in the hierarchy.

Comment: which are the primary key in those tables? and also structure of table?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the good way. 
Now with your CTE you can create SUBSELECT with each Post subordinates and concat them, f.e. them with `FOR XML`

```
SELECT
   P.[Post Number],
   P.[Authoriser Post Number],
   P.[Post Name],
   (    
     SELECT 
            cte2.[Post name] + ', ' AS [text()] 
     FROM CTE cte2
     WHERE cte1.[Post Number] = cte2.[Post Number]
     ORDER BY cte2.[Post name] -- This is optional
     FOR XML PATH ('')
   ) [Subordinates]
FROM CTE cte1
```

Comment: Sorry, this will only show the direct subordinates. I suppose you need to display all subordiantes in other level.
In that case, SQL Server 2016 uses Hierarchy, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx This post describing how to create such hierarchical table https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677237.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer. This returns exactly what I need. Typical that I get the answer soon after posting the question.

```
;WITH CTE AS
   (
   SELECT
          P.[Post Number],
          P.[Authoriser Post Number],
          P.[Post Name]
   FROM
          Structure.Post P
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
          C.[Post Number],
          P.[Authoriser Post Number],
          C.[Post Name]
   FROM
          Structure.Post C
   JOIN
          CTE P ON C.[Authoriser Post Number] = P.[Post Number]
   ) SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE WHERE [Authoriser Post Number] IS NOT NULLORDER BY [Authoriser Post Number]
```

Thanks for everyone who took the time to look at this for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was an interesting exercise. Would you like to look at my solution?
You can get list of hierarchy or some it branch. It needs only to change conditions in the WHERE clause.

```
DECLARE @Structure TABLE
(
    [Post Number]   INT,
    [Authoriser Post Number]    INT,
    [Post Name] VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT @Structure
VALUES
(85, NULL, 'CEO'),
(86, 85, 'Development Director'),
(87, 85, 'Sales Director'),
(88, 85, 'HR Director'),
(89, 88, 'HR Manager'),
(90, 89, 'HR Officer'),
(91, 89, 'Recruitment Officer'),
(92, 89, 'HR Assistant'),
(93, 87, 'Sales Manager'),
(94, 87, 'Sales Manager'),
(97, 94, 'Salesman'),
(98, 94, 'Sales Support Officer'),
(95, 93, 'Salesman'),
(96, 93, 'Sales Support Officer'),
(99, 86, 'Web Design Manager'),
(100, 86, 'SQL Manager'),
(104, 100, 'Project Manager'),
(105, 100, 'SQL Developer'),
(101, 99, 'Web Developer'),
(102, 99, 'C# Developer'),
(103, 99, 'Project Manager')

;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT  [Post Number], [Authoriser Post Number], [Post Name], 1 AS Num, CAST('/' + CAST([Post Number] AS VARCHAR) + '/' AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS Hierarchy
    from @Structure
    WHERE [Authoriser Post Number] IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.[Post Number], s.[Authoriser Post Number], s.[Post Name],
        p.Num + 1, CAST(Hierarchy + CAST(s.[Post Number] AS VARCHAR) + '/' AS VARCHAR(4000))
    from @Structure s
        JOIN cte p ON p.[Post Number] = s.[Authoriser Post Number]
)

SELECT c2.[Post Number], c2.[Authoriser Post Number], SPACE(c2.NUM*5) + c2.[Post Name] AS [Post Name]
FROM cte c1
    JOIN cte c2 ON (c2.Num > c1.Num AND c2.Hierarchy LIKE '%/' + CAST(c1.[Post Number] AS VARCHAR) + '/%') OR c2.[Post Number] = c1.[Post Number]
WHERE c1.[Post Name] = 'CEO'
ORDER BY c2.Hierarchy
```